# Display text but update with code in a combobox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, bindingsource

I am new to VB.NET and I am afraid I have been spoiled by the Powerbuilder datawindows.

In a MySQL table there are columns which contain codes where the details are in a joined table. For example table boats has a column material containing “A” (Aluminium). “G”(GRP) etc.

I have a form with a number of tabs including a tab “BoatsTab”. I don’t use a datagridview but drag the columns from the dataset to the form. There can be multiple rows. What I am trying to do is display the material as “Aluminum” and to change the value by selecting from a drop-down ComboBox. Naturally updating should use “G” and not “GRP”. I can place a ComboBox on the form and populate it with a class containing code and description and retrieve the code from the selected item but this only works for one row as there is only one cb.

Is this possible?

Comment: Share your code. Your question is not brief.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don’t have any relevant code as I am still looking for a solution but I will try re-phrase the question as short as possible. 
A table “materials” contains a materialcode and description. A table “Boats” has a foreign key “materialcode”. In my form I need to display the column boats.materialcode as the description from table “Materials” and update the **code** by selecting from a (combobox?) containing the description.
I hope this is sufficient information and thank you for your trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Windows Form ComboBoxes, you can display a value which is different than the actual "database" value.

For this you have to use the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the `ComboBox` class.

Cheers

Comment: I would some aditional help with this but the question was too long. I will accept this and post another question. I must avoid thanks,  but....